# Javascript Relational Database

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays

Long story short : I'd like to treat several javascript associative arrays as a database (where the arrays are tables). The relations could be represented by special fields inside the arrays. I'm not interested in the persistence aspect of a database, I only want to be able to query the arrays with a SQL-like language and retrieve sets of data in the form of associative arrays.

My question : Is there any javascript library that has such features ? Otherwise, is there any library that can at least take care of the SQL-like language part ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some googling found this: http://ajaxian.com/archives/two-js-solutions-to-run-sql-like-statements-on-arrays-and-objects which seemed interesting.

Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks. We are trying to minimize the need to query some distant databases made mostly of static information. The idea is to load them once into arrays and query them locally instead of making a remote call every time an information is needed.

Comment: Do you really need the SQL language to do that? You can certainly store everything in javascript, and just read the arrays programatically.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the closest thing to what you need is the [jLinq library](http://www.hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq). It can operate with js objects and arrays much in the same way you would do with a database, but in a slightly different way. You don't really write queries, but use methods to construct them. Overall it's way better I think.

Comment: jLinq seems to be exactly what I wanted, i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while searching something sort of related.  Wanted to share with you (9 years later, I do realize) that I have the same want/need, often, where the script I'm working on has a lot of cross-referencing to do between various sources of information.  I use PowerShell.  Enumerating arrays of objects, from within a loop, which is enumerating other objects, is just bad/slow/horrible.

To date, my solution has been to take all my arrays and then make hashtables from them, where the key/name is a property value that is common across all the arrays (e.g. ObjectId (GUID)), and the value is the entire object from the array.  With this, while in my loop which is enumerating Array#1, I can check for the presence of this current item in any of the other arrays simply by checking the existence of the key in the corresponding hashtables, and that way there's no enumerating the other array, there's just direct , equal effort access to the correct item in the array (but really coming from the newly built hashtable).

So my arrays are just temporary collection buckets, then everything I do from there uses the hashtables, which are just index/lookup tables.

What I was searching for when I stumbled here, was for solutions to keep track of all the different hashtables in the building/planning phase of my scripts.